# Rotate Octagon 90 degrees

Tags: modeling

I want to know how to rotate Octagon perfectly 90 degrees.

well, I'm not good to explain so here's a picture.

[image]

There are 1 edge drawn in red,
set this edge to base and rotate perfectly 90 degrees like 2.

Any good idea pls.

Comment: it's not clear, from your left picture to the right one, the rotation is not 90°, it's 22.5°. You can choose the center of rotation on the header menu > Pivot Center, for example it can be the 3D cursor or the last selected vertex...

Comment: Make sure your object is centered at the 3D-cursor, press ctrl + R, Z, type 22,5 at the num-keypad, press enter and you're done.

Comment: Im new to this site so forgive me, pardon me i dont understand cleary, why 22.5? is it 100% right?　 [link](https://youtu.be/EYI-yYeZ-0w) this is maya but its what i want to do can do this thing in edit mode?

Comment: Sorry Explain this is so hard. and i don't know what words to use.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you question, all you have to do is select your shape, press R to rotate, then press 22.5 to give the rotation value (in your case if you want the octagon to be flat you only need to rotate it 22.5° because 360° / 8 = 45, and 45 / 2 = 22.5)

Comment: Thanks for answer to my question. i did what you say and it looks work.But i'm afraid if i put wrong number, So If, i want to make sure, for example, Octagon rotated 22.5(has thickness) , select Octagon round edge or thickness (thickness means face that made by extrude) and Snap to Plane (Because plane face are 100% flat) Can i do that?